# Copy number file format issue (Need to modify the structure)

Tags: python, r, format

I have a file in a special format .cns,which is a segmented file used to analyze copy number. It is a text file, that looks like this (first line plus header):

```
head -1 copynumber.cns
```

chromosome,start,end,gene,log2 chr1,13402,861395,"LOC102725121,DDX11L1,OR4F5,LOC100133331,LOC100132062,LOC100132287,LOC100133331,LINC00115,SAMD11",-0.28067

We transformed it to a .csv so we could separate it by tab (but it didn't work well). The .cns is separated by commas but genes are a single string delimited by quotes. I hope this is useful. The output I need is something like this:

gene                    log2

LOC102725121            -0.28067

DDX11L1                 -0.28067

OR4F5                   -0.28067

PIK3CA                   0.35475

NRAS                     3.35475

The fist step, would be, to separate everything by commas and then, transpose columns? and finally print de log2 value for each gene that was contained in that string delimited by quotes. If you could help me with an R, or python script it would help a lot. Perhaps awk would work too. 
I am using LInux UBuntu V16.04 
I'm not sure if I am being clear, let me know if this is useful.
Thank you!

Comment: You've identified several tools for the job.  What have you tried?  What didn't work about those attempts?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Hope following code in Python helps

```
import csv

list1 = []
with open('copynumber.cns','r') as file:
    exampleReader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in exampleReader:
        list1.append(row)

for row in list1:
    strings = row[3].split(',')   # Get fourth column in CSV, i.e. gene column, and split on occurrance of comma
    for string in strings:  # Loop through each string
        print(string + ' ' + str(row[4]))
```